# Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException error with scanner

Tags: java, exception, java.util.scanner, nosuchelementexception

My function code is

```
public static void marime(ArrayList<Aplicatie> x) {
       Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in); 
            System.out.println("Introdu diapazonul de marime dorit pentru a primi rezultatul");
        int a = scan.nextInt();
        int b = scan.nextInt();
        scan.close();
            //System.out.println("Aplicatiile cu marimea intre " + a + " si " + b + " sunt: ");
            for(Aplicatie i: x) {
                if(i.marime <= a & i.marime >= b)
                    System.out.println(i.denumire + ' ' + i.versiune + ' ' + i.limba + ' ' + i.companieProducatoare + ' ' + i.tip + ' ' + i.cuSunet + ' ' + i.cuInstalare + ' ' + i.marime + ' ' + i.licenta);
        }
    }
```

My first scanner is declared:

```
static ArrayList<Aplicatie> citire() throws IOException {
        int n;
        ArrayList<Aplicatie> x = new ArrayList<Aplicatie>();
        try (Scanner cin = new Scanner(System.in)) {
          {  
      //  here is more code where I read more variables but I preferred not to copy.
                cin.close();
            }
        } 
        return x;
    }
```

```
//My error is: Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:937)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1594)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2258)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2212)
    at testing.marime(sarcina.java:158)
    at testing.main(sarcina.java:183)
```

**158:         int a = scan.nextInt();
183:         marime(x);**

The array is declared in the main method.

I am sorry for my English and for the Romanian words, but the error is global and understandable by everyone.

Comment: it is hard for me to understand your code, but NoSuchElementException means that the value that are you trying to request does not exist. Tip: all local variables needs to be instantiated whit a value.

Comment: Yes, but I want to enter the value from the keyboard.

Comment: You should not be closing scanner based on `System.in` because it also closes the keyboard input stream.

Comment: There are 2 different scanners, and even if I don't close it, the same thing happens.

Comment: I found the solution, I declared only one scanner at the beginning of the class and I used it everywhere, I closed it only after I read everything, it was my mistake that I tried to use 2 different scanners, thank you all for the answer.